# »Eine Aussicht für« vs »Eine Aussicht auf«

Tags: meaning, preposition

Ich möchte gerne den Unterschied zwischen »Eine Aussicht für etwas« und »Eine Aussicht auf etwas« kennen.
Sind sie gleich?

Comment: *Eine Aussicht für etwas.* does **not** exist. What does exist is *Eine Aussicht für **jemanden**.* And that's the difference to *Eine Aussicht **auf** etwas.*

Comment: If you have an example for "Aussicht für *etwas*", please post it, and we can comment in more depth.

Answer (score 2):

Die beiden Ausdrücke »Aussicht für« und »Aussicht auf«
sind definitiv **nicht** gleich und auch **nicht** austauschbar.

Es ist auch zu beachten, dass »Aussicht auf« die reguläre Form ist und in der deutschen Sprache auch viel gebräuchlicher ist als »Aussicht für«, wie dieses [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=aussicht%20f%C3%BCr%2Caussicht%20auf&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1720&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CAussicht%20f%C3%BCr%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CAussicht%20auf%3B%2Cc0)-Diagramm zeigt.

Hier einige Beispiele, in denen »Aussicht auf« häufig benutzt wird:

> Der Tourist hat ein Zimmer mit **Aussicht aufs** Meer gebucht.
>
> Der kranke Patient hat gute **Aussichten auf** Genesung.

Hier einige Beispiele, in denen »Aussicht für« benutzt werden kann:

> Der Minister stellt die Ergebnisse der letzten Wahl und auch eine **Aussicht für** 2017 vor.
>
> Ich habe immer die (Wetter-)**Aussichten für** die kommenden zwei Tage im Blick.

»Aussicht für etwas« wird also m.E. nur benutzt, um auf Zukünftiges vorauszuschauen. Aber selbst dafür wird es sehr selten verwendet.

Answer (score 0):

Hier ein paar mehr Beispiele von wohlgeformten Sätzen, in denen **"Aussicht für"** vorkommt:

> Haben Sie ein Zimmer mit Aussicht für meine Frau?
>
> Das ist keine gute Aussicht für die Türkei.
>
> Ein Zimmer mit viel Aussicht für wenig Geld
>
> Da ist ja endlich ein Mann in Aussicht für dich!

Ich hätte allerdings einer Kritik, dass dies kaum erhellt, mit welcher Präposition "Aussicht" zu gebrauchen sei, wenig entgegenzusetzen.

Answer (score 0):

Die Präpositionen "für" und "auf" sind beide mit dem Wort "Aussicht" möglich, sogar gleichzeitig, z.B. "Aussicht auf Besserung für den Kranken" oder "Aussicht für Passagiere auf den Sonnenuntergang". Sie bringen unterschiedliches zum Ausdruck:

- Mit "für" wird das Subjekt der Aussicht verbunden, also die Person, die auf etwas sieht.
- Mit "auf" wird das Objekt der Aussicht verbunden, also was die Person sieht.